# HPC parallelization error 'std::bad_allocstd::bad_alloc' during DIA-NN analysis

Tags: parallel-processing, bioinformatics, hpc

I am trying to parallelize an analysis pipeline for proteomic data, using a published tool (DIA-NN). As described by the developers, this can be achieved by splitting the pipeline into 5 unique components, with the two slowest parts running in parallel (the manual isn't updated, but this is what I'm working with: https://github.com/bigbio/quantms/issues/164).

I have the pipeline working cleanly on 1 sample, as well as 3-4 samples in parallel (although sometimes it fails with 4...), so I don't think this is an issue with the pipeline specifically. Trying to run across more than that always fails, and thus is likely an issue with my own attempts to parallelize. While 3 samples across 1 node works, 6 samples across 2 node fails, so it's not simply an issue with core allocation.

The error suggests a memory allocation issue, and my guess is that there is a memory leak in my code. I wouldn't expect to hit allocation issues with so few samples if the pipeline was working correctly, but I can't figure out a way to overcome it. Alternatively, there is just a fundamental limitation with the HPC memory (and am working with the cluster support team to ensure this isn't the case).

Example script, using 1 node with 96 threads:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J diann
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --partition=XXX
#SBATCH --qos=XXX
#SBATCH --time=0-00:05:00 #D-HH:MM:SS
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL 
#SBATCH --mail-user=XXX
#SBATCH --account=XXX

echo "starting dia-nn run"

module purge

module load anaconda3/2022.05-gcc-12.2.0-oqiw76n
source activate $DATA/myenv

module load openjdk/11.0.17_8-gcc-12.2.0-o2utqnb #updated java

# function to specify max number of jobs
function pwait() {
    while [ $(jobs -p | wc -l) -ge $1 ]; do
        sleep 1
    done
}

# set working directories 
mkdir "full-diann-trial"

LIB="timsTOF/libs/"
INPUT="timsTOF/2023/20231030"
OUT="full-diann-trial"

mkdir "$OUT/part2"
mkdir "$OUT/part4"

PART2="$OUT/part2"
PART4="$OUT/part4"
FILES=("$INPUT"/*.d)

F_OPTIONS=""
for FILE_PATH in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    FILENAME=$(basename "$FILE_PATH" .d)
    F_OPTIONS+=" --f $FILE_PATH"
done

PART2_PARAMS="--cut K*,R* --var-mod UniMod:35,15.994915,M --var-mod UniMod:1,42.010565,*n --monitor-mod UniMod:1 \
        --lib $LIB/lib.predicted.speclib \
        --min-pr-mz 400 --max-pr-mz 1000 --min-fr-mz 100 --max-fr-mz 1700 \
        --threads 12 \
        --missed-cleavages 2 --min-pep-len 7 --max-pep-len 50 \
        --min-pr-charge 2 --max-pr-charge 4 --var-mods 2 --verbose 3 \
        --individual-windows \
        --temp $PART2 \
        --min-corr 2.0 --corr-diff 1.0 \
        --quick-mass-acc \
        --individual-mass-acc \
        --time-corr-only"

### step2 - analysing each run separately with the in silico library generated in step 1, generate quant files

echo "starting part2"

for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    ./bin/diann-1.8.1 $PART2_PARAMS --f "$FILE" --out "$OUT/step2-$(basename "$FILE" .d)" &
    pwait 6
done

wait

echo "finished part 2"
```

Here, 'pwait 3' will work, more than that fails.

Example error:

```
Loading spectral library timsTOF/libs//lib.predicted.speclib
[0:17] Library annotated with sequence database(s): timsTOF/fasta/Combined_proteins_48970.fasta; timsTOF/fasta/Mouse_uniprot-proteome_UP000000589_2023.04.27.fasta
[0:17] Protein names missing for some isoforms
[0:17] Gene names missing for some isoforms
[0:17] Library contains 17129 proteins, and 16776 genes
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_allocstd::bad_alloc'
'
  what():    what():  std::bad_allocstd::bad_alloc

/var/spool/slurm/slurmd/job923716/slurm_script: line 20: [: -ge: unary operator expected
/var/spool/slurm/slurmd/job923716/slurm_script: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: I see neither a line for memory request, nor for number of cores in the SLURM headers. Meaning, the default (whatever this is in your case) are used, and this well can be too little memory. So set a header for memory.

Comment: Thank you! With the slurm configurations I am automatically allocated all cores on a node, but the memory request here fixed the issue.